# Onclick Sets a Cookie For a Page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I Have this button on my site which opens new page on click, so i was trying to set a unique cookie for every users who click on it and access the new page , if someone try to access the new page directly by url than they should see a sample text and redirect automatically to the button page. How can i do that?

```
<div class="button">
 <a href="/" target="_blank">CLICK HERE TO GET THIS..!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
     <a href="" onclick="what_i_want()" id="the_button" target="_blank">CLICK HERE TO 
     GET THIS..!</a>
</div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
function what_i_want()
{
    var cookie_name=Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;  //random name for example;
    var cookie_value=" any value";  // << you also can get value from function >> what_i_want(par,par2,par,3);
    document.cookie = cookie_name +'='+ cookie_value;
    document.getElementById('the_button').href="TARGET_LOCATION";
}
</script>
```

Comment: what will be code for checking this cookie and if its empty how to show a div and redirect them automatically to the old page?

Comment: send cookie_name too. by GET method. Like this : document.getElementById('the_button').href="TARGET_LOCATION?check_cookie="+cookie_name ;

so now you can get that random name from link and check cookie with that

Answer (score 0):

Even without any sort of database, you can use the local storage built into a web browser to save items. Set the app as your "new tab" page in your browser and the to-dos will persist on your local computer as long as you don't clear the cache.

Previously, cookies were the only option for remembering this type of local, temporary data. Local storage has a significantly higher storage limit (5MB vs 4KB) and doesn't get sent with every HTTP request, so it can be a better option for client-side storage.

Here is an overview of `localStorage` methods.

```
Method              Description

setItem()       Add key and value to local storage
getItem()       Retrieve a value by the key
removeItem()    Remove an item by key
clear()         Clear all storage
```

Try it:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Now if you test `localStorage` in the console again, you'll find your new key and value.

```
Storage {key: "value", length: 1}
```

More info on how to use `localStorage` you can find [Here](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/)

Comment: can u show me the code part?